# How to find which Expression(s) matched in a linq query

Tags: linq, expression

I have a set of expressions saved in a database table. The requirement is to match a bunch of these expressions against a Linq (to Entities) query. For performance sake I am combining the expressions with an OR clause so I can run the query just once instead of running the same query for each expression one by one. Is there a way to find out out which of the expressions really matched against the query?

Thanks
A

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you have tried. The question is a bit too vague at this point.

Comment: Hi Jim, I have a bunch of letters that must get flagged when a customer record is saved. Each letter has its own condition for when it must generated. If the customer's address has been saved then flag a letter to vendors in the that area. If the Customer has saved some insurance details then flag a letter to the insurance company etc. These are a bunch of search expressions associated with each letter. When a customer record is saved, I OR these expressions  and run them against the customer record. I need to know which of the expressions returned true so I can flag the associated letters.

Comment: Can you post an example of the query? How exactly are you combining the expressions?

Comment: Hi svick, I combine the two expressions using Expression.Or, get the resulting BinaryExpression.  Then I create a lambda expression using the Expression.Lambda<T> method and pass the combined BinaryExpression and the parameters from the two expressions to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The only way is evaluate each response separately, and then once you have all the resultsets, union them in LINQ.

It's really not easy to do in the database either, at least I 'm pretty sure.

HTH.

Comment: thanks for the answer. That's what I have found with all my efforts so far. Really hoping someone has a magic solution for it :)